# How to use template tags inside safe filtered content in django

Tags: html, django, django-templates

`<strong>{{ var.name }} </strong>`

The above code is saved inside database with a field name `data` . While rendering template with `{{ data | safe }}` , it gives output as **{{ var.name }}** as strong , but doesn't load the content inside `var.name`.

Is it possible to do so.

Comment: You try {{var.name|safe}} right?

Comment: no, i tried {{ data|safe }} , data contains <strong>{{ var.name }}</strong> .

Comment: could you share the view and the html part?